# Rails: Converting currency from form to big decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integer, bigdecimal

I have a `form_for` which has a `text_field` which accepts a number that the user types in a format such as this: `$45,000.45`.

However, the database saves this as a `BigDecimal` value.

Whats the most efficient way to convert this to a big decimal before saving, and to display it on the view as such?

Answer (score 2):

The `money` gem (and `money-rails`) is a very effective way of handling amounts like this.

Answer (score 1):

How I've handled this in the past is using the Rails helper method [number_to_currency](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency).

```
number_to_currency(1234567890.50)                    # => $1,234,567,890.50
number_to_currency(1234567890.506)                   # => $1,234,567,890.51
number_to_currency(1234567890.506, :precision => 3)  # => $1,234,567,890.506
```

You can save the field as a normal number, and Rails will format it to $'s.

Comment: I actually need to do the inverse of that, allow a user to enter a currency ($1,345.56) and then save that as a BigDecimal.

Comment: @Stefan it's an honor to have you comment! @zasman what I would do is create a number input prefixed with a dollar sign: `$<%= f.number_field :dollar_amount %>`. It keeps the type correctness of a number with a BigDecimal field.